# Auto-remove unused tags

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

Drupal 7.

We want to remove tags (of Tags vocabulary) automatically when all pages referring to this tag are removed.

Is there a module for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a couple of modules that might help:

- [Taxonomy Orphanage](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_orphanage) (specifically the cron interface)

  > This module provides interfaces (drush, cron, admin form) for removing orphaned taxonomy term references from entities.
- [Field reference delete](http://drupal.org/sandbox/drothstein/1775816) (sandbox only)

  > This module removes references to a deleted entity from fields stored in an SQL database. It exists to prevent stale references to non-existent content from causing unexpected problems (for example, when the referencing content is being displayed).